# Buildbot has too many pending jobs and has stopped building at all

Tags: buildbot

I encountered a problem in which buildbot has too many pending jobs and has stopped doing any more builds. Even when I restart the buildbot, the pending jobs do not go away. I want to be able to do the build and remove the pending jobs. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to cancel pending builds you must have this feature enabled in the
`authz.Authz` setting in the `master.cfg` file of your buildmaster,e.g.

```
authz_cfg=authz.Authz(
    # change any of these to True to enable; see the manual for more
    # options
    gracefulShutdown = False,
    forceBuild = True,
    forceAllBuilds = False,
    pingBuilder = False,
    stopBuild = True,
    stopAllBuilds = False,
    cancelPendingBuild = True,
)
```

[Documentation here](http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.4p2/WebStatus-Configuration-Parameters.html)

Once you've done that you'll need to restart your buildmaster. Then, on the web-status
page of any builder, you'll see buttons to cancel any pending builds as well
as the running build.